# how to timeout a script when it runs into an event it can't handle autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script that opens a browser and saves a webpage and I want it to cancel the job on a time out. If it's waiting for a window that doesn't show up to stop running and start over. How would I go about this? Here's my short script:

```
Run, www.google.com
WinWaitActive ahk_exe firefox.exe
Sleep, 1000
Send ^s
WinWait, Save As
Send ^{Backspace}
Sleep, 1000
SendRaw www.google.com.html
Sleep, 500
ControlClick, Button2, Save As,, Left, 1,  NA
```

Comment: See the `ErrorLevel` and `Examples` sections of those commands' documentations.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `Timeout` parameter of `WinWaitActive`:

From [the docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm):

> ### WinWaitActive / WinWaitNotActive
>
> Waits until the specified window is active or not active.
>
> > `WinWaitActive , WinTitle, WinText, Timeout, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText`

If it takes longer than the value in the `Timeout` parameter, then the script continues and the variable `ErrorLevel` is set to `1`/`True`.

By putting this entire script under a [`Label`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Labels.htm) (here called `savePageSubroutine`), we can go back to this point with a `goto` statement.

```
savePageSubroutine:
    Run, www.google.com
    WinWaitActive ahk_exe firefox.exe,,1000 ; Tune this value to taste
    if (ErrorLevel)
        goto savePageSubroutine
    Sleep, 1000
    Send ^s
    WinWait, Save As
    Send ^{Backspace}
    Sleep, 1000
    SendRaw www.google.com.html
    Sleep, 500
    ControlClick, Button2, Save As,, Left, 1,  NA
return
```